# PHP mailing script which are generate bounce back mail and their log

Tags: php, html, css, email, mailing

I have a one mailing script which are run perfect right now . Using .csv we need fetch all email address on that and send one by one mail automatically.

Which script are run as sending mail to multiple user email address.

Now i want to create one extra feature on that "**BOUNCE BACK MAIL**" . When email sending script is working at that time which email address not send mail . i want to generate bounce email log generator in .txt file or other file.

Is there any script related this requirement .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With which MTA you send your emails? Normally it can't be done to track the bounced mails. You have to write a script which reads all the mails from the bounce inbox and write each bounced mail in a log.

Comment: Hi XyNNN,
no MTA i had used i just create one PHP script with multiple mail sending at a time . now i want to just detect bounce mail address.

Comment: This is not possible because PHP send only the mail to the SMTP server and don't wait if the mail is delivered correctly - The server just working off the mailing queue.